# How to group field as array in sequlize?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sql table products:

```
+-----------+------+--------+
| productid | rate |  name  |
+-----------+------+--------+
|       100 |   80 | orange |
|       100 |   10 | orange |
|       102 |  100 | banana |
+-----------+------+--------+
```

I want to group by `productid` all the rates to array..

How to get using `sequelize` the following object (via find method)?

```
{
 products: [{
  productid: 100, 
  name: 'orange',
  rate: [ 80, 10 ]
 },
 {
  productid: 102,
  name: 'banana'
  rate: [100]
 }
]
}
```

Comment: research row_to_array() and array_to_json() functions if you use postresql

Comment: I want to use sql solutions :)

Comment: which sql driver?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table name is `demo` table

```
SELECT *
FROM demo frst, demo snd
WHERE frst.productid = snd.productid
Group By  frst.productid;
```

this will give the expected result in the sql, if you use `sequelize` than it will give the same result i think so or some what you will have to modified after response